# Store difference between two date fields as new column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two different DATE fields in the same table. Change_date and End_date, I need to get the difference between two (in days) and store as a new column in that same table.

I've attempted a datediff function but that seems to only work in Ms sql and not oracle.

Comment: You can just use `end_date - change_date` to get the days in between. You might need to round/truncate if you have time components and are expecting integers.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, add a virtual column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (difference GENERATED ALWAYS AS (end_date - change_date))
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (change_date DATE, end_date DATE);

INSERT INTO table_name (change_date, end_date)
VALUES (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), SYSDATE);
```

Then, after adding the virtual column

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | CHANGE_DATE | END_DATE | DIFFERENCE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | 2021-11-05 16:27:32 | 4.68578703703703703703703703703703703704 |

*Note: If you want whole days then use `TRUNC(end_date -change_date)`.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db024a226f537009b0c08ed5442e3497)*